# Eclipse JAX-RS (REST Web Services) 2.0 requires Java 1.6 or newer

Tags: eclipse, spring, web-services, jax-rs

i'm new to web service and i'm trying to do a project using jax-rs rest and spring in eclipse.
I use java 1.8 but eclipse shows me an error that jax-rs 2.0 requires java 1.6 or newer error and my project won't work

This is the project explorer and error's screenshot. I tried to google it but can't get any english solutions

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

Edit : It seems like the screenshot's quality is low if i try to display it so here is the imgur link for the screenshot for better quality
https://i.stack.imgur.com/90wV7.png

Comment: Is maven compiler plugin set to 1.8? It default to 1.5 if you don't declare it to override the java version

Comment: @peeskillet where can i view it?

Comment: In you pom file. It should be under `<plugins>` If you don't see it, you can and it. Just google maven-compiler-plugin. It not difficult to add. After you add it, update the project

Comment: @peeskillet added the maven-compiler-plugin version 3.3 to pom.xml and updated the project. Still got the same error

Comment: You set the source and target to 1.8?

Comment: If that still doesn't work, try and right click on the project -> properties -> Java Compiler -> Look at compliance level. You can change it by deselecting the "Use compliance...:". But I think this should be consistent with the Maven plugin source/target version

Comment: Sorry I was on my tablet, couldn't get you some code. But for the plugin, under the `</version>` add `<configuration><source>1.8</source><target>1.8</target></configuration>`, then Right click project -> Maven -> Update Project

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks for the configuration, after i did it, the error vanished
**edit: add it as an answer so I can mark it as correct answer**

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Maven projects come with a bunch of plugins applied implicitly to the build. One of them being the `maven-compiler-plugin`. Unfortunately the Java version for the plugin defaults to 1.5. Most Maven project you see will override the Java version simply by declaring the plugin (in your pom.xml file) and configuring the Java version

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Eclipse (with m2e plugin) will set the compiler compliance level to the setting in the plugin. You can view this by going to

> Right click on the project -> properties -> Java Compiler -> Look at compliance level

#### UPDATE

Instead of the above compiler plugin configuration, you can also simply just do

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

The default plugin configuration will look for these properties. It's a lot less verbose than re-declaring the plugin.

After adding the properties or the compiler plugin to your pom.xml, you might need to update the project. See [Manish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57977444/2587435).

Comment: adding those 2 properties resolved my problem. thanks

Comment: You saved me a lot of effort. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I know the topic is old but I had the same problem and it's hard to find informations on it.
So set the properties wasn't enough for me, I had also to delete the project from Eclipse, then delete the .project file and reimport the project as a Maven project (even if I created it as a Maven project already) like it is answer [on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406491/why-does-eclipse-kepler-sr1-error-with-jax-rs-2-0-requires-java-1-7-or-newer?rq=1).

Answer (score 3):

those who are doing with properties way and if it is not working do this step.

 in Pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

After that do this:

```
  project folder-> maven--> update project--> check force update-->ok
```

After that do

```
 project folder-->run as-->mvn build with goal eclipse:eclipse
```

you don't need to re-import the project as suggested in other answer/

Answer (score 0):

Just got to the path of the project and go to settings and find the xml file named "org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core" and change the version of java from there