# Eclipse JAX-RS (REST Web Services) 2.1 requires java 1.8 or newer

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, jersey

I am using Eclipse and trying to make Rest-API with Maven-Jersey-Tomcat. The server is working fine but I'm getting the two following errors when trying to run the URL which I have specified in `@Path`. But when I try to access the `MyResource.java` it works and shows output.

Please help me
Maven Java EE configuration Problem

1. JAX-RS(REST Web Services) 2.1 can not be installed (one or more constrained have not been satisfied.
2. JAX-RS(REST Web Services) 2.1 requires java 1.8 or newer

I have tried to change JDK version but not working.

Comment: Did you [change the maven-compiler-plugin version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30083646/2587435).

Comment: i had changed jersey version not maven compiler plugin... do i need to do it??

Comment: Yes, look at the post I linked to. They are facing the same error

Comment: it worked...Thanks a lot Paul...I have seen your comments are there also....Great budy...Keep it up... Please add me for future conversation....I will ask you directly if i have any problem.....I am new in programing world.....Thanks once again